# Hello everyone, I'm currently doing a school project and I'm using python, But I keep running into this error "string argument w/o encoding"

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

So basically on this block:

```py
if len(args) > 0:
    text = u''join(map(bytes, args))
else:
    text = sys.stdin.read().strip()
```

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/test.py", line 198, in <module>
   text = u''.str.encode()

   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'.
```

If anyone can help me please do. Thank u in advance :)

Comment: The line with the error isn't in the posted code snippet.

Comment: You're missing a `.` in `u''.join`. That must be a copying error. Please use copy and paste rather than retyping.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you lost the `.` between `u''` and `join` in your posted code.
- Second, from your posted error log, we can know there is an another syntax error for `text = u''.str.encode()` in your /home/pi/test.py file. It should be `text = u''.encode()`.